# Asp.net core posting checkbox data from View to Controller

Tags: forms, asp.net-core, razor, model-binding

I'm new to Asp.net core and was wondering what I am doing wrong.
I have models like this that are populating my View:

```
Public class Person
{
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }

Public class Collection
{
     public List<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

A View that takes a form of checkbox items and is meant to set 'isSelected' to true.

```
@model Collection
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostSelectedPerson", "Person", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <tbody>
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.People.Count; i++)
                    {
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="@Model.People[i].IsSelected" value="true" checked /></td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.People[i].IsSelected)
                        <td>
                            @Model.People[i].Id
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
                    }
                </tbody>
            }
```

And an Action that is meant to be passed the updated Collection model.

```
     [HttpPost]
     public IActionResult PostSelectedPerson(Collection c)
        {
           //return something.
        }
```

The View is populated, but when the form is submitted, the action gets an empty Collection.
I expect a Collection with a list of Person with isSelected set to true for those with checkboxes marked.

Answer (score 0):

> The View is populated, but when the form is submitted, the action gets an empty Collection.

If you'd like to include both `Id` and `IsSelected` info in formdata and post them to action, please use additional hidden form field for `Id` property and specify **name** attribute for hidden field to match property of custom model class, which would help bind value to properties of the model automatically, like below.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostSelectedPerson", "Person", FormMethod.Post))
{
<table>
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.People.Count; i++)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input asp-for="@Model.People[i].IsSelected">
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.People[i].Id
                <input type="hidden" name="People[@i].Id" value="@Model.People[i].Id" />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.People[i].Name
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Test Result

[image]

> I expect a Collection with a list of Person with isSelected set to true for those with checkboxes marked.

If you want only selected person data are post to action, you can dynamically generate/populate `formdata` based on selected rows, then make ajax request to post it to your action on JavaScript client.